# What is the difference between the x.509 V3 extensions Basic Constraints and Key Usage to create a CA certificate?

Tags: security, encryption, ssl, cryptography, x509certificate

These two actions seem to do the same:

- using the **Basic Constraints** extension in a X.509 Certificate to signify that it is a CA certificate and
- using the **Key Usage** extension e.g. to signify that the public key can be used for certificate signining.

What is the difference between these extensions?
Do they serve same purpose or complement each other?

Comment: Is your question solved? Then please accept the best answer. Otherwise please mention what is still missing here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"Key Usage" defines what can be done with the key contained in the certificate. Examples of usage are: ciphering, signature, signing certificates, signing CRLs.

"Basic Constraints" identifies if the subject of certificates is a CA who is allowed to issue child certificates.

For a certificate that can be used to sign certificates, the info is in some sense duplicated:

- X509v3 Basic Constraints:  CA: TRUE --- Can sign certificates
- X509v3 Key Usage: Key Cert Sign   --- Can sign certificates

But "Basic Constraints" will also specify the maximum depth of valid certification chain.

Though it is duplicated, you need to specify both, according to [RFC 3280 --- X.509](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3280#page-29).
This is the relevant paragraph from the RFC (page 29):

> The keyCertSign bit is asserted when the subject public key is
> used for verifying a signature on public key certificates.  If the
> keyCertSign bit is asserted, then the cA bit in the basic
> constraints extension (section 4.2.1.10) MUST also be asserted.

Comment: "the info is in some sense duplicated" Do you know if implementation doing validation, accept either Basic Constraints or Key Usage to signify CA when doing cert path validation?

Comment: @user384706: No, you need both. I have updated my answer with the info.

Comment: There are also certificates that may be issued by non-CA certificates: see [RFC 3820 - not 3280](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3820)

Answer (score 2):

Key Usage describes intended purposes of the certificate.

Basic Constraints extension describes how deep the certificate chain that has the certificate as it's top can be. In other words, this extension is used by CAs to restrict activity of their sub-CAs when the sub-CA certificate is issued. If toplevel CA gets a sub-CA , it allows sub-CA to issue end-user certificates, but doesn't allow sub-CA have it's own sub-CAs.

Comment: @Eugene:Can we have a certificate that has the Key Usage extension, that it can sign certificates, but the Basic Constraint missing?Is this the same as having a certificate with basic constraint to be CA with infinte certificate path?

Comment: @user384706 From RFC 5280, section 4.2.1.9: " Conforming CAs MUST include this extension in all CA certificates that contain public keys used to validate digital signatures on certificates and MUST mark the extension as critical in such certificates." So it looks like the answer to your question is "this would be violation of the standard". However, I did see certificates without such extension.

Comment: @Eugene:Java's PKIX apis (checked it with Java6u23) does accept CA certificates with only KeyUsage (not Basic Constraints). Does this mean that java violates the RFC?

Comment: @user384706 who am I to judge them? I've quoted the RFC, which says that the extension must be present. However, not accepting such certificates would lead to compatibility problems, so I guess Java creators accept non-compliant certificates (at least by default).

Comment: @Eugene:Compatibility problems?Between what?Compliant and non-compliant implementations?

Comment: @user384706 with sites using such certificates, obviously.

Comment: @Eugene:May be you know this better, but why sites would deploy such certificates that are non-compliant?

Comment: @user384706 I assume this happens because it's not webmaster's job to check standard-compliance of the certificate, issued by CA. I.e. if the CA issues such certificate, it's CA's guilt. The owner of the web site should not be penalised by impossibility to connect to this site.

Comment: @Eugene:When you blame CA, are you refering to some custom internal CA in a private organization?I assume that organizations like Verisign and the like, are carefull to be compliant to the standard, right?