# Difference between .cert vs .cacert (X.509)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have received three files from my hosting company who bought the X.509 certificate for me.

`.key` file - thats the private key
`.cert` file - ?
`.cacert` file - ?

Whats the difference between the two?

Comment: Why the downvote? Was my question not clear enough. At least leave a comment, so  I can improve my question. Downvotes with no comments is useless. Thanks!

Comment: I did search it before by entering `.cacert and .cert` into google.

Comment: Filenames, and extensions, are not so relevan. You will find many different conventions, so it is best just to look at the content, do not stare too mych at the exension. Now, intuitively `.cacert` should be your CA certificate corresponding to the `.cert` certificate itself. But again, look at the content first. Note however that your question is not strictly a programming question, hence a little offtopic here.

Comment: I might agree that is not a strictly programming question but many questions relating X509 certificates poping up on stackoverflow. should we all downvote them because they are not strictly a programming question? How about this one here: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795256/what-is-the-difference-between-the-x-509-v3-extensions-basic-constraints-and-key?rq=1`

Comment: 1) I did not downvote you 2) the fact there are other off topic questions do not legitimate new offtopic ones :-)  You will find others saying it is on topic, so it can be argued endlessly. I stated my opinion, your question has no solution involving a programming activity hence it is offtopic for me. But the important point is that you found a solution and documented it here so it is great.

Comment: Personally I believe we don't need a downvoting police for questions but thats a another endless topic for discussion. If we think the question is "flawed" how about  leaving a comment to 1) improve the question or 2) make more self-effort to do a research (because the answer is just a quick google search) . The downvoting police thinks that this site needs to be kept `pure and uncontaminated` by so called `unworthy questions`. We should help each other out, but that has nothing do to with helping each other. For me, that only shows prepotency by judging others who really looking for help.

Comment: Just curious, what questions do you think should be downvoted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using the following command:

`openssl x509 -noout -text -in <filename>`

I have found out that  `.cert` is public key certificate of my own site and `.cacert` is the intermediate certificate authority who issued the certificate.

Comment: As i was explaining in my answer I found an openssl command to display the content of certificates. From there I made an educated guess of the type.

Comment: The filename extension is not really a reliable guide to the contents.